What is the time-complexity of BLAS level 2 and 3 functions from a vendor which optimized the operations?
BLAS level 2 performs Matrix-vector multiplications, and I know this is O(n^2) in time, when the matrix is shaped (n, n) and the vector is shaped (n, 1).
BLAS level 3 performs Matrix-Matrix multiplications, and I know this is O(n^3) in time, when the matrices are shaped (n, n).
My question is, are the above statements about the time-complexity of these operations (dgemv and dgemm), true for, say, Intel-MKL, or AMD-BLIS, or Cray-Libsci libraries?
From what I understand, the engineers from such organizations create small-sized kernels which are fine-tuned based on the target architecture and are used in the degemv() and dgemm() operations.
Maybe the SIMD-operations they cleverly use just replace/change/lower-down the constant coming in front of the n^2 or n^3 ? (we are talking of big-O notation, so there has to be a constant (prefactor) in front of the term in the parentheses).
Thank you!

SIMD operations have no impact in general on the complexity, especially not here. (SIMD) Registers have a fixed size. No (classical) machines in the world can compute O(n) operations in a bounded time. It is always a bounded number of operations (mainly because information require physical space and machines takes a fixed-size space and the observable universe is bounded, not to mention nothing can be smaller than the plank constant).

Regarding BLAS matrix-multiplication, there is AFAIK no standard. However, the very-simple naive algorithm runs in O(n^3) so having a bigger complexity than that for an implementation would be insane. Implementations can use the Strassen algorithm for large matrices. Strassen as a better complexity : approximately O(n^2.8). However, Strassen is numerically instable so it is often not used in practice (AFAIK not OpenBLAS, nor BLIS and probably not the MKL by default). There are theoretically better algorithms but none are currently practicable. Most are galactic algorithms.

The presentation https://jianyuhuang.com/presentations/strassen_sc16.pdf tends to confirm the above statements. The benefit of using Strassen is rather small in practical use-case (i.e. using multiple cores and a quite numerically-stable approach) and only on rather big matrices.
